# Running a JMeter script with nohup giving "No such file or directory"

Tags: jmeter, nohup

Running a load simulation with master slave model, while running the test from command line using nohup giving "No such file or directory".

So I have two azure ubuntu vms (one is master and one is slave) and connected over putty. While executing long run load test I got a power outage and the test got killed. So tried using "nohup" but getting "No such file or directory" error.

The following command I triggered after I goes inside the Jmeter bin directory

Command without "nohup" (working fine till my connection is live)

```
JVM_ARGS="-Xms1024m -Xmx2048m" && export JVM_ARGS && ./jmeter -n -t /home/performance/LoadTesting/Portal-8HR.jmx -R 192.168.2.32:1099 -GTest_Name=LongDurationLoadTest -GTest_Triggered_By=LoadExecuter -Gtest_Id=200Con_8HR_Test01
```

Command Tried with "nohup" (not working)

```
JVM_ARGS="-Xms1024m -Xmx2048m" && export JVM_ARGS && nohup ./jmeter -n -t /home/performance/LoadTesting/Portal-8HR.jmx -R 192.168.2.32:1099 -GTest_Name=LongDurationLoadTest -GTest_Triggered_By=LoadExecuter -Gtest_Id=200Con_8HR_Test01 &

JVM_ARGS="-Xms1024m -Xmx2048m" && export JVM_ARGS && nohup "./jmeter -n -t /home/performance/LoadTesting/Portal-8HR.jmx -R 192.168.2.32:1099 -GTest_Name=LongDurationLoadTest -GTest_Triggered_By=LoadExecuter -Gtest_Id=200Con_8HR_Test01" &

JVM_ARGS="-Xms1024m -Xmx2048m" && export JVM_ARGS && nohup ./jmeter -n -t /home/performance/LoadTesting/Portal-8HR.jmx -R 192.168.2.32:1099 -GTest_Name=LongDurationLoadTest -GTest_Triggered_By=LoadExecuter -Gtest_Id=200Con_8HR_Test01 > /home/performance/RunTest/test2.txt 2>&1 &
```

Remember these parameters are important as I have a Grafana back-end listener which capture all these data with all the results.

Also I tried with

```
nohup ./jmeter -n -t /home/performance/LoadTesting/Portal-8HR.jmx -R 192.168.2.32:1099 -GTest_Name=LongDurationLoadTest -GTest_Triggered_By=LoadExecuter -Gtest_Id=200Con_8HR_Test01 </dev/null >nohup.out 2>nohup.err &
```

But getting,

```
Creating summariser <summary>
Created the tree successfully using /home/performance/LoadTesting/Portal-8HR.jmx
Configuring remote engine: 192.168.2.32:1099
Starting distributed test with remote engines: [192.168.2.32:1099] @ Wed May 06 12:32:30 UTC 2020 (1588768350878)
Error in rconfigure() method java.rmi.MarshalException: error marshalling arguments; nested exception is:
        java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.jmeter.JMeter$ListenToTest
Remote engines have been started:[]
Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/HeapDump/ThreadDump message on port 4446
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not fully getting what you're trying to achieve, the correct equivalent of your command would be something like:

```
nohup bash -c "JVM_ARGS=\"-Xms1024m -Xmx2048m\" && export JVM_ARGS && ./jmeter -n -t /home/performance/LoadTesting/Portal-8HR.jmx -R 192.168.2.32:1099 -GTest_Name=LongDurationLoadTest -GTest_Triggered_By=LoadExecuter -Gtest_Id=200Con_8HR_Test01 & ./jmeter -n -t /home/performance/LoadTesting/Portal-8HR.jmx -R 192.168.2.32:1099 -GTest_Name=LongDurationLoadTest -GTest_Triggered_By=LoadExecuter -Gtest_Id=200Con_8HR_Test01 & ./jmeter -n -t /home/performance/LoadTesting/Portal-8HR.jmx -R 192.168.2.32:1099 -GTest_Name=LongDurationLoadTest -GTest_Triggered_By=LoadExecuter -Gtest_Id=200Con_8HR_Test01" 2>&1 &
```

If the only concern is network connectivity loss between putty, whatever it is, and Linux Azure VM you could use a terminal multiplexer like [screen](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-use-linux-screen/) or [tmux](https://www.hamvocke.com/blog/a-quick-and-easy-guide-to-tmux/) on the Azure VM side so you can attach to the running session when needed from this or another machine.

There are also a lot of ways to schedule a Linux job starting from simplest [cron](https://opensource.com/article/17/11/how-use-cron-linux) definitions, [systemd timers](https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/scheduling-tasks-with-systemd-timers.html) or you can use a "heavy artillery" like [Jenkins](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/continuous-integration-101-how-run-jmeter-jenkins) which allows flexible scheduling and kicking off jobs on other triggers. If you go for Jenkins you can enjoy the benefits of the [Performance Plugin](http://jenkinsci.github.io/performance-plugin/RunTests.html) allowing marking builds as failed or unstable depending on test metrics received and plotting performance trend charts

Comment: any clue how to resolve this error 
Error in rconfigure() method java.rmi.MarshalException: error marshalling arguments; nested exception is:
        java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.jmeter.JMeter$ListenToTest

Comment: This is a separate topic not connected to the original question by any means and I cannot say anything meaningful without seeing the [jmeter.log file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging), either you specified wrong IP address or your test is using a [JMeter Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) and the slave doesn't have this plugin installed

Comment: When I used the above command(modified one), I am getting this error which I mentioned above. 

Error in rconfigure() method java.rmi.MarshalException: error marshalling arguments; nested exception is: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.jmeter.JMeter$ListenToTest